# Explode column containing list of json-strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table in a `mysql` database which looks like this:

```
ID                                      CONFIG
0              276  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
1              349  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
2              378  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
3              381  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
4              385  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
```

where the elements in the `CONFIG` column all have the form:

```
{"posit":[{"type":"geo_f","priority":1,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_m","priority":2,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_i","priority":3,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_c","priority":4,"validity":0}]}
```

Now, I know how to "explode" this table for the first level:

```
SELECT *,
CONFIG ->'$.posit' as Position
FROM mytable;
```

which return

```
ID                             CONFIG          Position
0              276  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...    [{"type":"geo...
1              349  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...    [{"type":"geo...
2              378  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...    [{"type":"geo...
3              381  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...    [{"type":"geo...
4              385  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...    [{"type":"geo...
```

where the elements of `Position` are lists of json-strings:

```
[{"type":"geo_f","priority":1,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_m","priority":2,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_i","priority":3,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_c","priority":4,"validity":0}]
```

But, I do not have a clue of how to take the next step to "explode" the elements of `Position`. The resulting table should have:

1. 4 times the number of rows as the original table since there are four json-strings. I.e., 4 rows for each `ID`.
2. The addition of columns `type, priority, validity`.

I tried different way to extract this information:

```
SELECT *,
CONFIG ->'$.posit' as Position,
Position ->>'$.type' as Type
FROM mytable
```

but that evidently failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a JSON_TABLE function in mysql 8.
Does it work for you?

```
SELECT jt.*
FROM z as mytable
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit', 
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (ID FOR ORDINALITY,
                                      type     VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.type',
                                      priority VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.priority',
                                      validity VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.validity')
) jt
```

Or in case you need only for row but as columns it is much more simple

```
SELECT mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit[0].type' as type_0,
       mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit[1].type' as type_1,
       mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit[2].type' as type_2,
       mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit[3].type' as type_3
FROM z as mytable
```

PS: As mentioned in comment you wanted ID from `mytable`:

```
SELECT mytable.ID, 
       jt.*
FROM       z AS mytable
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(mytable.CONFIG -> '$.posit',
                                        '$[*]' COLUMNS (type     VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.type',
                                                        priority VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.priority',
                                                        validity VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.validity')
) jt;
```

Comment: Wrong - applicable to scalar or single-row value only. Select `id` from source table and rename parsed ORDINALITY column, this allows to parse a rowset.

Comment: Great! The last piece of code worked perfectly! Thank you!